# Extending a 2-complex embedded in $\mathbb{S}^3$ into a simply connected one

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let $C$ be a connected simplicial 2-complex, and $f: C \to \mathbb{S}^3$ an embedding in the 3-sphere. Assume that each of the link graphs of $C$ is connected, and that $f$ nice, e.g. locally flat or piecewise linear.

Is it true that there is a *simply connected* 2-complex $C'$, containing $C$ as a topological subspace, and an embedding $f': C' \to \mathbb{S}^3$ that coincides with $f$ when restricted to $C \subseteq C'$?

(If we relax the condition that $f'$ extends $f$, then the statement is proved by Carmesin in Theorem 7.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.04643. Carmesin obtains an $f’$ with a rotation system that coincides with that of $f$ when appropriately restricted, but this is weaker than what I am asking for.)

Comment: The fact that $f$ is PL makes life very pleasant.  I spent some time thinking about the wild case but it feels much harder.  I think (???) that it is ok, but the proof is much more delicate... The fact that link graphs are connected will prove that the one-skeleton is tame.  So all of the wildness occurs at some Cantor sets inside of the two-cells.  We need to "herd" all of the the wild points in $S^3$ into a finite collection of three-balls and then carefully add two-cells $D_i$ (the cells of $C' - C$) so that $f'|D_i$ misses these three-balls... it is a mess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. [The tameness of $f$ makes our life *much* easier.]

It will be convenient for the proof to assume that $C$ is *pure*: that is, every vertex and edge of $C$ lies in some triangle of $C$.  If this is not the case, then glue triangles on until it is the case.

Take $D = f(C)$; since $f$ is piecewise linear $D$ is tame and we can work with $D$ instead of $C$.  Let $N$ be a very small regular neighbourhood of $D$. Note that $D$ is a *spine* for $N$ in the sense that $N - D \cong S \times (0, 1]$ (PL homeo).  Let $\tau_D : N \to D$ be the resulting deformation retraction.  (In fact, we can here get away with using nearest point projection.)  So $N \subset S^3$ is a PL sub-three-manifold and $S = \partial N$ is a separating surface.  Note that $S$ is need not be connected and may have two-sphere components.

Define $M$ to be the closure of $S^3 - N$.  Note that $S = \partial M$.

Let $E$ be a special spine for $M$. Again, we will assume that $E$ is pure.  (Note that this means that we will have use Bing's house with two rooms, or similar, as special spines for three-ball components of $M$.) Thus $M - E \cong S \times (0, 1]$. Again let $\tau_E : M \to E$ be the resulting deformation retraction.  We can no longer use closest point projection, but we  still arrange that $\tau_E$ is PL.

Let $\Gamma$ be a spine for the surface $S$; that is, $S - \Gamma$ is a collection of disks.  Again we assume that $\Gamma$ is pure - so while $\Gamma$ may have vertices of degree one, it does not have isolated vertices.  Also, we isotope $\Gamma$ slightly so that it is transverse to $(\tau_D|S)^{-1}(D^{(1)})$ and also to $(\tau_E|S)^{-1}(E^{(1)})$.

We build a two-complex from $$D \,\, \sqcup \,\, \Gamma \times [-1, 1] \,\, \sqcup \,\, E$$ by attaching $\Gamma \times \{-1\}$ to $D$ via $\tau_D$ and attaching $\Gamma \times \{1\}$ to $E$ via $\tau_E$.  This is the desired complex $C'$; the map $f'$ is inclusion.  Note that $S^3 - C'$ is a collection of (open) three-balls.  That is, $C'$ is a spine for $S^3$.  Thus $C'$ is simply connected.

Comment: Nice, thank you! When you write $\Gamma$ may have vertices of degree zero, I think you mean "degree one". I don't agree that "$C'$ is a spine for $S^3$" (it is if you remove a point from each chamber), but this is irrelevant.

Comment: Suppose now I want $C '$ to be `canonical' in the following sense. I have a finite group $H$ of isometries acting on $S^3$ mapping my original 2-complex $C$ onto intself. I want this action of $H$ on $C$ to extend to $C'$. A possible approach would be to repeat your construction of $C'$ on the quotient orbifold $S^3/H$, and lift the result back to $S^3$. Would this work?

Comment: Yes... I think so.  We take the quotient, take a regular neighbourhood $B$ of the orbifold locus, cut it into standard pieces with disks (so, balls about the vertices, solid cylinders about the edges) and add $\partial B$ and the disks to our spine.  Then we play the same game as before in $S^3 / H - B$.

Comment: @Agelos - I fixed the typo (about degree zero) you pointed out. Thank you!  Also, I suppose that I am working with a more general definition of "spine".  Probably I should not do that! But it feels like the correct definition?  I mean, why not allow multiple three-balls in the complement of a spine?  The extra flexibility is very handy.

Comment: I'm fine with this extended definition, though I think you only used it in the sentence "That is, C′ is a spine for S3", which doesn't affect the rest of the discussion.